# Meu carrossel com bootstrap não está funcionando!

Tags: css, html5, bootstrap

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap/js/jquery.min.js">
</head>
<body>
<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
<ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>
<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
            <div class="item active">
                <img src="imagens/banner.jpg" alt="banner">
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img src="imagens/banner-02.jpg" alt="banner">
            </div>
        </div>
<a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
            <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Negada vai fechar sua pergunta. Você tem que dizer o que está acontecendo, qual o problema, qual o erro, colocar num Fiddle para testarmos...

Comment: Não está passando para a outra imagem, isso q está acontecendo.

Comment: Já coloquei o jQuery em primeiro e nada!

Comment: É que você está chamando o arquivo de Bootstrap JS e jQuery como estilos CSS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você está chamando os arquivos JS como Estilos CSS.
Troque isso:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap/js/jquery.min.js">
```

Por isto:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Lembrando que o `jquery.min.js` deve sempre estar em primeiro.

---

Você tem que colocar o ID da DIV como **`#myCarousel.`**

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel"></div>
```

No lugar de: `carousel-example-generic`

Comment: eu já arrumei e não funcionou :(

Comment: Veja se no console dá algum erro.

Comment: então eu coloquei isso ai e funcionou em partes, tipo quando eu espero um pouco a imagem troca, mas quando eu aperto a seta pro lado não troca

Comment: Tem como você colocar no JSFiddle pra eu ver ?

Comment: Achei o problema.

Comment: Cara eu subi esse teste pra voce ver http://www.cnvv.com.br/teste/teste.html

Comment: Editei minha pergunta com a resolução do problema.

Comment: Agora funcionou! Obrigado!